# Get number of characters in a single line android EditText

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout, android-edittext

In `EditText`, when a very long text is entered, edit text moves the text into another line. How can I find out the index in the string that `EditText` has ended the line on?

ie When you type in `EditText`, after some words your `EditText`'s line ends, and your cursor moves to new line. This is the point I want to find, after how many characters your cursor moves to new line.

So, in this image I want to get index of last *"e"* (from 'online') in the first line, *"e"* of 'Google' in 2nd and so on:

[image: i.e. index of last **e** in first line, **e** of google in 2nd and so on..]

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Add more content to your question

Comment: @BidhanA .. see...its too simple... When you type in Edittext , after some words your Edittext's line ends , and your cursor moves to new line , this point I want to find , after how many characters your cursor moves to new line...
Got it now???

Answer (score 3):

```
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {   
                int currentline=1;
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int count)
                {
                    if(edittext.getLineCount() > currentline)
                    {
                        Log.d("new line ", "Line");
                        Log.d("no. of characters in"+currentline+" line", count-1);
                        currentline++;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: this is main logic , now you can change it as per your requirement. thank you all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the line count by `editText.getLineCount();`
But I dont think you can get the content in every line individually.

**EDIT:**
Fixing the characters will help you to achieve your goal, but its not much better thing to do.

In XML you can add this line to the `EditText` `View` where 140 is the maximum number of characters:

```
android:maxLength="140"
```